# Как в Visual Studio 2017 поменять цвет полей класса

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Как в Visual Studio 2017 поменять подсветку цвета идентификаторов полей класса для проектов С#?

Для проектов на С++ есть отдельная опция для изменения цвета (второй скрин), для C# такую опцию не могу найти.

[image: С++]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А не могли бы вы предоставить скрин того, что хотите изменить?

Comment: Все цвета в студии меняются в "Параметры" -> "Шрифты и цвета". Конкретно то, что вы выделили называется "Идентификатор".

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, ответы - в ответы

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я не считаю это ответом, ибо я не знаю что именно хочет автор. Данная настройка меняет почти все имена в коде на указанный цвет, а не только то, что выделено на скрине. По этому я не могу считать это ответом. Это больше скажем так наводка, нежели ответ.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, любой ответ лучше чем никакого, вопрос без ответа будет бесконечно подниматься Духом и засорять ленту.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Тоже верно. Хорошо, оформлю ответом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Стандартное решение

Для изменения цветов в Visual Studio существует специальный раздел "Шрифты и цвета". Находится он в "Среда" -> "Параметры" -> "Окружение" -> "Шрифты и цвета".

К примеру, хотим мы изменить указанный вами текст на красный:

- В "Шрифты и цвета" выбираем в выпадающем списке "Текстовый редактор".
- Ищем в нижнем списке "Идентификатор".
- Сбоку от списка есть настройки цвета, а также опции для изменения шрифта. К примеру в "Основной цвет элемента" выбираем "Красный".
- Жмем кнопку ОК.

Результат:

[image: Text Color]

p.s. Но тут одно но! Стандартно студия для языка c# покрасит вам все названия в один цвет (будь они локальные или нет).

### Решение на основе ReSharper

- Для начала активируем опцию, которая переключит цвета в редакторе на те, что предоставляет ReSharper. Для этого заходим в настойки ReSharper "Code Inspector" -> "Settings" -> "Color identifiers".

[image: ReShaper Options]

- Далее идем в уже знакомые нам настройки студии, в раздел "Шрифты и цвета".
- Нас интересует "ReSharper Field Identifier", ставим ей текст на красный.

Результат:

[image: ReShaper result]

На просторе интернета есть еще пару плагинов, которые помогут в решение этой задачи, один из таких [SemanticColorizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndreasReischuck.SemanticColorizer), но я с ними не знаком...

Comment: На локальные переменные настройка тоже влияет?

Comment: нужно только чтобы красным цветом выделялись только поля класса, а не все идентификаторы

Comment: @АндрейNOP К сожалению она влияет на все, что только можно. Походу стандартными методами изменить цвет отдельных частей не получится. Знаю, что в ReSharper'e есть данная возможность.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, ну так дополните ответ

Comment: @АндрейNOP Дополнил ;-)